# SQL Server, Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server Management Studio I created a table named 'Login' with two columns named "UserName" and "Password".

```
CREATE TABLE Login(
        UserName varchar(50) NOT NULL;
        Password varchar(50) NOT NULL;)
```

Then, i tried to add values to those columns with this script:

```
INSERT INTO Login (UserName) VALUES ('admin');
INSERT INTO Login (Password) VALUES ('password');
```

But i get the following errors:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Password'
>
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserName'

I already checked other posts about it but i could not find a solution, any help ?

Cheers

Aurel

Comment: Insert them all at once; this is very basic: `INSERT INTO Login (UserName, Password) VALUES ('admin', 'password');`

Comment: you're trying to create **TWO** new records, each of which is missing a value for a notnull field. if those are supposed to be ONE user, then you do a SINGLE insert and provide BOTH values to that one single insert. you can't "insert" a single record twice. you insert a new record (which creates the record), then you can update it later with other information.

Comment: You should also look into using salted and hashed passwords instead of clear text.

Comment: The error messages really say it all, if you think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happened because you insert first `UserName` and `Password` is empty and you don't allow null values in both columns, the same is with the second insert.

Use one query

```
INSERT INTO Login (UserName, Password) VALUES ('admin', 'Password');
```